# Trying to compile a simple code for class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Here is my example code:

```cpp
// FileName: test.cpp
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class Form1: public Form
{
    public: Form1()
    {
        this->Text = "My Form";
        this->Size = Drawing::Size(250, 150);

    }
};

[STAThread]
int main() {
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1);
}
```

Compile this code using `cl /clr test.cpp /link /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:main`
under the Deverloper Command Prompt

So, I type the block of code into notepad and save it as a txt file. Then, I open the developer command prompt in visual express and type in the `cl /clr test.cpp /link /subsystem:windows /entry:main` and it gives me an error, as shown in the screen shot:

[image].

[I changed the file name to test.cpp and recompiled the code using the line:
    `cl /clr c:\game\test.cpp /link /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:main`
 But it still errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceDvC.png)

After resaving the file as an all file type rather than a .txt file type, I was able to make the file a .cpp and be able to be read by the compiler, but it says that there is a fatal error c1083, that it cannot find text.obj.

Comment: It looks from the screenshot like you didn't save it as test1.cpp

Comment: @cliffordheath, I agree with you. Kei, you have to save your text file as test.cpp and provide a complete address to the compiler.

Comment: hmm I tried renaming the file test.cpp but that didn't work either... as for a complete address...

c:\game\test.cpp

so I should compile using...

cl /clr c:\game\test.cpp /link /subsystem:windows /entry:main

but it says that the file or directory doesn't exist. hmm.

Comment: Instead of screenshot with others commands, it could be clearer to put only the error messages you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have rights to comment but I have that feeling that you have saved it as a .txt file. This means that your file name could actually be `test.cpp.txt` instead of your intended filetype (ie. `test.cpp`).

On the Notepad in which contains your code, press `CTRL+SHIFT+S`. This brings up a new "Save-As" where you can safely change the type. The type of the document is shown as a dropdown box below the text field where you name your file. Change it to `All Files`

In case you can't edit the file type on Notepad for some reason, open a new notepad, copy the exact code to that Notepad and use the save function. Name it as `test.cpp` and change the type below the name of the file from .txt to `All Files`

**EDIT FOR SECOND ANSWER** The problem with Command prompt is that it reads relative paths rather than full paths for commands what you can do is to `cd` into your directory.

```
cd C:\game
//your cl code which I don't want to copy&paste for no reason this time using the exact command that your paper have listed
```

The application will be created under the same directory. Hope it helps.

Comment: That actually did it! But now it says test.cpp : fatal error c1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'test.obj': Permission denied

I looked up the error code, it says that it means it cannot find the file... which would make sense, I did not make a test.obj file. This is very confusing... Thank you for hanging in there with me

Comment: I will appreciate the accept answer if this helps you. :)

Comment: I still can't compile this thing so it's not quite done ha ha... the goal is to just make a window frame.

Comment: Just try `cl /clr test.cpp' and this should create a test.exe

Comment: Perfect! I typed in cd C:\game and hit enter, which brought me to that directory then typed in cl /clr test.cpp and boom, it compiled. Amazing thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

It like the compiler says. test.cpp does not exist and "*.txt" is no known extension. Rename your file from "test.txt" to "test.cpp" and try again.